# Ajax post response returns empy if database connection fails

Tags: php, ajax

I am building a PHP project that has a simple form with 3 fields. This form is connected with a MySQL table named "article". When I submit the form, with the help of jQuery and Ajax I display a notification message: eg "Submitted successfully" on success submission or "Something went wrong" on fail submission. My problem is that this notification message works fine on successful submission but if there is an error - For example if database connection fails - then the notification message is empty and it doesn't display the error message! I added the  `console.log(error);` in my code so I can check the console for errors but there are no errors displayed there. What I 'm doing wrong?

Here is the PHP code I wrote for submit the form in the DB:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../config_db.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// Retrieve the submitted values
$article = $_POST["article"];
$author = $_POST["author"];
$tags = $_POST["tags"];

// Create a new database connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check the connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    $response = array(
        "status" => "error",
        "message" => "Error: Failed to connect to the database."
    );
} else {
    // Prepare the statement
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO article (article, author, tags) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    // Bind parameters to the statement
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $article, $author, $tags);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $response = array(
            "status" => "success",
            "message" => "Article submitted successfully!"
        );
    } else {
        $response = array(
            "status" => "error",
            "message" => "Error: " . $stmt->error
        );
    }

    // Close the statement
    $stmt->close();
    
    // Close the database connection
    $connection->close();
}

// Send the JSON response
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

And here's the html form with ajax:

```
 <form method="post" action="submit_article.php" id="articleForm">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea class="textarea" id="article" name="article" placeholder="Enter the article..." required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Author name..." required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" id="tags" name="tags" placeholder="Add some tags...">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field is-grouped">
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="button is-link" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="button is-link is-light" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='index.php'">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
 <div id="notification" class="notification is-primary"></div>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#articleForm").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

            // Send the form data via AJAX
            $.ajax({
                url: "submit_article.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    // Display the notification message
                    var notification = $("#notification");
                    notification.text(response['message']);
                    notification.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();

                    // Clear the form
                    $("#article").val("");
                    $("#author").val("");
                    $("#tags").val("");
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    // Display the error message
                    var notification = $("#notification");
                    notification.text(response['message']);
                    notification.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                    console.log(error); // Log any errors to the console
                }
            });

            return false; // Prevent default form submission
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? In recent versions, mysqli has been changed to raise exceptions when errors occur, so you need to use `try/catch` to catch the errors.

Comment: What do you see in the raw response in the Network tab of the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `$connection->connect_error` will give you an error for well known errors, such as wrong user / password / permission, etc.

Having a real connection issue will cause `new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` to throw an exception. Hence your script is simply interrupted by the generic exception handler and the error-response you are generating due to `$connection->connect_error` will never be generated.

To cover that, you need to use a try/catch-block and generate a proper response there.

Update:
With `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` you can force mysqli to throw exceptions for well known errors as well - then you can ommit the additional `If` check and handle everything from within the catch-block.